# Unable to get URL-based context in django-template-repl

Tags: python, django

I'm trying out django-template-repl for debugging a template issue and it's pretty awesome.

One of the features of the tool is that you can go:

```
python manage.py templateshell -u /admin/
```

and pull up the context for that url location.

Unfortunately no matter what configuration of /admin/ or other urls in my site I try to pull up, I always get

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/template_repl/utils.py(11)pdb_with_context()->None
```

I am running it with the optional --pdb flag to see if I'm getting context in. And oh, my tab completion doesn't work either. :(

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well guess the tab completion doesn't work because it loads pdb instead of ipdb... you're sure you have ipdb installed (probably youre in some virtualenv without it?)

Comment: woops, true. will give that a shot.

Comment: The message you saw is expected if you are using standard pdb (but should be followed by a prompt starting with "(Pdb)"). Lazerscience is right that PDB doesn't have tab completion but you can install ipdb, and it will automatically use it. Tab completion in the template syntax is possible (if you don't pass the --pdb flag). If you are on a Mac I'm not sure if it will work unless you have GNU readline installed. You can install it with homebrew if you don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around to trying the solution codysoyland put up in the comments section. Sure enough, you need to have ipdb installed for this functionality to work. Now it works great.